# git pull Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists

Tags: git

I use the `git pull` command to update the code `git clone` by `my colleagues`, encountered the following problems：

> Permission denied (publickey).
>
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights
> and the repository exists.

Comment: His credentials could be off, or maybe the repo URL has changed, or the write access rights have changed.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Directory permissions is 777，repo URL is right，I can `git pull` the code which `git clone` by myself，but I  cannot `git pull` the code `git clone` by others.

Comment: `but I cannot git pull the code git clone by others` <-- what does this mean?

Comment: Note that if you run a google search for `Permission denied (publickey)` you will find many useful tidbits.

Answer (score 8):

If your repository is cloned over HTTPS, then you probably might have to switch your remote GitHub URL. This can be achieved by using the below commands:

- `git remote -v` - This will list your existing remote command using the `-v` verbose option. This will show you whether you are using an HTTPS protocol or an SSH protocol.

If my guess is correct and you are using SSH protocol then you have to switch from HTTPS to SSH using the below command:

- `git remote set-url origin <GitHub_HTTPS_URL>`

Now, you can try again to issue your `git pull` command. You can use the `set-url` option to switch back and forth from HTTPS protocol to SSH protocol and vice versa any number of times. Hope this helps!

Comment: attempted n number of solutions from Stackoverflow but only this worked.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding origin before pull as in,
`git pull origin [branch-name]`

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this several times.  Things that we could look at:

1. Make sure that the existing repository exists by typing `git remote -v`

   - if you get the an error - Most likely this occurred because the folder that contains the `git` got deleted, or renamed.
   - you may want to find the existing file or just clone the repo again (which may take some time, and you may have to start coding the part you had in the lost file).
2. If this is not the case, probably something to do with your ssh-key.  You must either set it up first - or you have not been given access.  Try this link for a complete step for ssh-key configuration.  [This link here](https://help.github.com/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/)

Good luck.

Comment: You could, also, change the 'remote' from using SSH to HTTPS.
`git remote set-url <name> https://path_to_repo`  Most likely <name> is 'origin'

Answer (score 1):

> Permission denied (publickey).

This indicates that you are using ssh to access the remote repository, and that your ssh key is not accepted by the server. This can be because

- you don't have the key on your local machine
- your key was not found by your local ssh client
- the key was revoked on the server

You can check this by running `git remote -v` and run `ssh -vvv` with the server account.

For example, if your remote is `git@github.com:git/git-scm.com.git`, you run `ssh -vvv git@github.com` to examine your problem.